# Why are operators sometimes stand-alone and sometimes class methods?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why is that sometimes an operator override is defined as a method in the class, like

```
MyClass& MyClass::operatorFoo(MyClass& other) { .... return this; };
```

and sometimes it's a separate function, like

```
MyClass& operatorFoo(MyClass& first, MyClass& bar)
```

Are they equivalent?  What rules govern when you do it one way and when you do it the other?

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145022
(Evidently my search-fu wasn't good)

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between global operator and member operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145022/difference-between-global-operator-and-member-operator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to be able to do something like `3 + obj` you have to define a free (non-member) operator.

If you want to make your operators protected or private, you have to make them methods.

Some operators cannot be free functions, e.g., `operator->`.

This is already answered here:

[difference between global operator and member operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145022)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a binary operator like +, you normally want type conversions to be performed on both operands. For example, a string concatenation operator needs to be able to convert either or both of its operands from a char * to a string.  If that is the case, then it cannot be a member function, as the left hand operand would be *this, and would not have a conversion performed.

E.g.:

```
operator+( a, b );  // conversions performed on a and b
a->operator+( b );  // conversion can only be performed on b
```

Answer (score 1):

If the operator is defined outside of a class it's considered global, and allows you to have other types appear on the left hand side of the operator.

For example, given a class `Foo`, with a global operator `+` you could do:

```
Foo f;
Foo f2 = 55 + f;
```