# c++ error: invalid operands of types 'Matrix*' and 'Matrix*' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have an exam about c++. There is description below:

- Matrix *m2 = new Matrix(3,4,9);  → 3x4 matrix with 9’s
- matrix operations → m2=m2+m3

I am trying to sum m2 and m3 and place m2. But there is an error: invalid operands of types 'Matrix*' and 'Matrix*' to binary 'operator+'.

main.cpp:

```
    int main(){
     Matrix *m2= new Matrix(3,4,9);
     Matrix *m3= new Matrix(3,4,2);

     m2= m2+m3;

     return 0;
     }
```

matrix.h:

```
      class Matrix{

      private:
      int x,y;
      vector<vector <int> > matris;

      public:
      Matrix(int row,int col,int z);
      Matrix* operator+(Matrix* no2);
      };
```

Matrix.cpp:

```
  Matrix::Matrix(int row,int col, int z){

        Matrix::x=row;
        Matrix::y=col;

        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            matris.push_back(vector <int>(y));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<Matrix::x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Matrix::y;j++){
                Matrix::matris[i][j]=z;
            }
          }
        }

Matrix* Matrix::operator +(Matrix* no2){

    Matrix* temp = new Matrix(this->x,this->y,0);

    for(int i=0;i<this->x;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<this->y;j++){
            temp->matris[i][j]=this->matris[i][j]+ no2->matris[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use pointers at all here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between global operator and member operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145022/difference-between-global-operator-and-member-operator)

Comment: @Axalo no it does not. The problem is pointers not global vs member

Comment: `Matrix *m2= new Matrix(3,4,9);` -- No.  Get rid of all the pointers and most, if not all of your problems would be solved.  There is no reason whatsoever to have a single `new` in your program, as `Matrix` is copyable with no issues, by default.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your declaration of `operator+`

```cpp
Matrix* operator+(Matrix* no2);
```

Actually, `operator+` is a member function so it can only be called through objects.

So the call `m2 + m3` translates to `m2.operator+(m3)`, but in your code m2 is a pointer and this syntax becomes invalid.

Your operator expects an **object at LHS** and a **pointer at RHS**.

In `m2 + m3` both are pointers, for which there is no suitable operator defined.

**Solution**

*Less work (ugly)*

```cpp
m2 = (*m2)+m3;
```

here you are **dereferencing the object** that m2 points to.

*More work (less ugly)*

```cpp
m2 = m2+m3;
```

but before this, you have to define `+` for 2 pointers globally(outside class)

```cpp
Matrix* operator+(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2) {
// do stuff
}
```

You will have to play with public/friend

I understand it's for class but you should not use pointers unless you really need to reconsider every object only approach.

There is a memory leak in `m2 = m2 + m3` (bad thing, eats RAM) here you're assigning m2 new location without deleting the old pointed object. So there is a Matrix object (>60-90) bytes lost which you can't access.

This can be easily made without using pointers and you will learn very much. Mind your deadlines. Hope it helps.

Comment: If it needs access to the private data he could declare it inside the class as `friend Matrix* operator+(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: Function declaration will be in class and friend as prefix, while definition should be outside and no need to prefix friend before definition.

Answer (score -1):

The operator you wrote could be called as

```
// this is only for demonstration, not real code!
Matrix *m_p1;
Matrix *m_p2;
Matrix m3;   
//...
m_p2 = m3 + m_p1;
// exactly the same as
m_p2 = m3.operator+(m_p1);
```

However, `operator+` is expected to take a `const Matrix&` as parameter and return a `Matrix`. Simply removing all pointers from your code will make it already almost correct.